# Can forward declaration be automated?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, forward-declaration

I'm writing C++ in Code::Blocks and there's one thing that's slightly bothering me. The forward declarations - can they be automated? Do I have to go to the top of the code each time I add or change a class/function and change the declaration as well? It seems like something the IDE should be able to handle for me. Or could that cause problems somehow?

Comment: Many modern IDE's have refactoring functionality to rename functions or to change their signature. What does the documentation of Code::Blocks say?

Comment: I don't know of any IDEs that auto-forward declare.

Comment: There are some IDEs with capability (settable options) that change all references to something if its name changes (e.g. if the name of a function changes in the definition, all other declarations/calls of that function are automatically changed). But I'm aware of no IDEs that will add forward declarations of something that is defined. (Also, technically, it is not necessary that every class function be declared before it is defined - it is only some books or style guides which advocate that, albeit some compilers can be configured to issue diagnostics if those guidelines are not followed)

Comment: You can use, from the "Search" menu, the command "replace" (in all project files).